# Guzzle 6 - How to pass query to redirects

Tags: php, redirect, query-string, guzzle6

I'm struggling to find out if there is a way to ask Guzzle to pass a query on to redirects. So that if I were to say

```
          $res = $client->request("GET", "https://google.com", [

                    'allow_redirects' => true,
                    'timeout' => 2000,
                    'query' => ['foo'=>'bar'],
          ]);
```

And lets say that (for some bizarre reason) google redirected to https://somewhere-else.com, I would like my foobar query to be passed on to that URL too

```
https://somewhere-else.com?foo=bar
```

Would love some help with this.

Thanks

Comment: won't be easy, what you are asking is real nonstandard behavior.

Comment: do you think so? Most redirects are to take the user from the now out-of-date address to the new location of the page, so in most cases wouldn't the query string also be required in the new location?

Comment: sure, but it's the server's job to provide you with an acurate redirection URI. It should propagate the query parameters on your behalf if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard mechanism in Guzzle to do that, because (as @Calimero already said) the HTTP spec doesn't assume this behaviour.

But you can copy and modify [the RedirectMiddleware](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/RedirectMiddleware.php), that Guzzle uses to handle `allow_redirects` option.